# Верно ли что: "С гарантирует отсутствие чего-либо по нулевому адресу"

Tags: c

Читаю справочник по Си и наткнулся вот на такую фразу.
"С гарантирует отсутствие чего-либо по нулевому адресу."
Второй абзац.
https://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/05/0507.html
Верно ли это утверждение?
Возможно, где то в стандарте это описывается?

Comment: Верно. Никакой объект не может находиться по адресу `NULL`.

Comment: только главное не путать "нулевой указатель" и NULL. NULL может быть не равным нулю

Comment: а что путать NULL -  это макрос, который должен указывать значение нулевого указателя.

Answer (score 2):

стандарт

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> An integer constant expression with the value **0**, or such an expression
> cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
> pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
> pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
> pointer to any object or function.

Там и говориться, что приведение нулевого указателя на любой тип не может быть равен реальному объекту или функции.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Это интересно.
А компилятор это как то реализует?

Comment: Компилятор всего лишь не размещает объекты и функции по нулевому адресу, так что это требование автоматически выполняется.